# C# : REST url returns 404 while the same URL works in web browser

Tags: c#, rest, get

I have this REST api (GET) which works fine in browser and spits JSON. I even tried the same API in Excel-VBA using XMLHTTP and it works fine.

But when trying to use the same API in C#, I am getting errors.

First I was getting:

> "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a send."

on the  the line

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;
```

Then I set the security protocol to `Tls11' and that error vanished.

Now I am geeting `404` in the resposne. The URL is correct.  I am able to run the same URL in web browser/VBA but not in C#.

Any suggestions or help?

Sorry, can't share the actual url as its work related.

```
     private const string URL = "https://xxx-production-api.abc.com/api/listings/1790956";
        private string urlParameters = "?apiToken=64842d73-9761-456b-86fa-a75a409273ce";
        public string  Download()
        {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
           new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4"); 
            // List data response.
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;  // Blocking call!
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)                
                    Console.WriteLine("Worked");                           
            else           
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase); 
            }
```

Comment: It's difficult to say that the URL is correct when the service returns a 404 (not found). Either the URL is incorrect, or the service is incorrectly returning a 404 (in which case there's probably not much we can do).

Comment: Try leaving the accept header in blank. Don't request for application/json, maybe the service is returning plaintext in JSON format.

Comment: @brank tried that  already :). I am in that phase where you randomly comment /uncomment lines and wish it works. no luck  yet.

Comment: Do you have any kind of authentication token or cookie in your browser? I ran into an issue once where it worked in the browser because I was signed in and unknowningly passing a cookie.

Comment: @DanWilson, nope. Just tried it in another browser altogether. The same url works in VBA too.  May be something different required for C#.

Comment: Can you post your VBA code? Maybe you are missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question :
Adding the user agent to headers solved the issue for me: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36")`

Copied and pasted the header info from Chrome dev tool and now the url is working in C# too.

Comment: It did not work for me. Do you have any more solution?

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your work firewall/proxy is not blocking the call.

I have run into a similar issues and this is the final code I use for my GET calls, see if it works for you. The main difference is that I don't use ".Result" I use "GetAwaiter().GetResult()".

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var method = string.Format("{0}{1}", ApiUrl, urlPart);
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(method).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();


        return data;
    }

    return default(T);
}
```